# antd tabs to use react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, antd

Wondering if there is a way we can render routes based on nested routes for each tab.

For example, when we browse to

```
http://localhost:3000/base/a
http://localhost:3000/base/b
```

We expect to have a `base` component which provides kind of layout and based on what `tab` we click it should render the `nested route` component.

The below example works without using react-router for rendering the tab's component.

**Below is route config**

```
<Route path={"/base:scope" } exact={true} { component: BaseComponent } />
```

**Below component will render the page with tabs**

```
import { Layout, Tabs, Row, Col } from 'antd';
import { Link, NavLink, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
export class BaseComponent extends React.Component {

    public state = {
        collapsed: false,
    };

    private onCollapse = collapsed => {
        this.setState({ collapsed });
    }

    get tabs() {
        const { collaborators, integration, settings, configuration, billing, tokens, referrals } = this.props;
        return [
            {
                key: 'a',
                tab: 'a',
                component: ComponentA,
                path: '/base/a',
            },
            {
                key: 'b',
                tab: 'b',
                component: ComponentB,
                path: '/base/b',
            },
        ];
    }

    public componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
        if (!_.isEqual(_.get(this.props, 'match.url'), _.get(props, 'match.url'))) {
            this.setState({ key: _.get(props, 'match.url') });
        }
    }

    public render() {
        const { renderer, router } = this.context;
        const { onLogOut, match, user, profile } = this.props;

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Header className={renderer.renderRule(styles.header, this.props)}>
                    <div className={renderer.renderRule(styles.title, this.props)}>
                        Account Settings
                    </div>
                </Header>
                <Content>
                    <div className={renderer.renderRule(styles.container, this.props)}>
                        <Tabs
                            animated={false}
                            defaultActiveKey={match.url}
                            onChange={key => router.history.push(key)}
                            className={`${renderer.renderRule(styles.tabs)}`}
                        >
                            {_.map(this.tabs, (record, index) => (
                                <TabPane
                                    key={record.path}
                                    className={renderer.renderRule(styles.pane)}
                                    tab={<span>{record.tab}</span>}
                                >
                                    {React.createElement(record.component, null, null)}
                                </TabPane>

                            ))}
                        </Tabs>
                    </div>
                </Content>
            </React.Fragment >
        );
    }
}
```

**Expectation:**

We want to write to be more react-router specific like

```
<Routes path={"/base"} exact={false} component={ComponentBase} />
<Routes path={"/base/a"} exact={true} component={ComponentBase} />
<Routes path={"/base/b"} exact={true} component={ComponentBase} />
```

But in this case we don't know how to render the page as the react-router not rending the page so we notice the tabs but no render content.

Here is the modified component without render content as we expect react-router to render the component.

```
export class BaseComponent extends React.Component {

    public state = {
        collapsed: false,
    };

    private onCollapse = collapsed => {
        this.setState({ collapsed });
    }

    get tabs() {
        const { collaborators, integration, settings, configuration, billing, tokens, referrals } = this.props;
        return [
            {
                key: 'a',
                tab: 'a',
                path: '/base/a',
            },
            {
                key: 'b',
                tab: 'b',
                path: '/base/b',
            },
        ];
    }

    public componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
        if (!_.isEqual(_.get(this.props, 'match.url'), _.get(props, 'match.url'))) {
            this.setState({ key: _.get(props, 'match.url') });
        }
    }

    public render() {
        const { renderer, router } = this.context;
        const { onLogOut, match, user, profile } = this.props;

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Header className={renderer.renderRule(styles.header, this.props)}>
                    <div className={renderer.renderRule(styles.title, this.props)}>
                        Account Settings
                    </div>
                </Header>
                <Content>
                    <div className={renderer.renderRule(styles.container, this.props)}>
                        <Tabs
                            animated={false}
                            defaultActiveKey={match.url}
                            onChange={key => router.history.push(key)}
                            className={`${renderer.renderRule(styles.tabs)}`}
                        >
                            {_.map(this.tabs, (record, index) => (
                                <TabPane
                                    key={record.path}
                                    className={renderer.renderRule(styles.pane)}
                                    tab={<span>{record.tab}</span>}
                                >
                                </TabPane>

                            ))}
                        </Tabs>
                    </div>
                </Content>
            </React.Fragment >
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to created RoutedTabs component using antd Tabs. I have added docstring for the same.

```js
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Tabs } from "antd";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import _each from "lodash/each";
import _map from "lodash/map";
const { TabPane } = Tabs;
/**
 * RoutedTabs is Ant Design based dynamic navigation tabs component.
 * It takes router config as prop and render the component as well as update the window location corrosponding to the tab.
 * Example of routeConfig
 * overview: {
        label: "Overview",
        component: RestaurantOverview,
        getRoute: url => url
    },
    menu: {
        label: "Menu",
        component: Menu,
        getRoute: url => `${url}/menu`
    },
    "menu-holiday-slot": {
        label: "Menu Holiday Slot",
        component: MenuHolidaySlots,
        getRoute: url => `${url}/menu-holiday-slot`
    }
    This will render three tabs Overview, Menu, Menu Holiday Slot and routes based on what getRoute method returns.
 */
const RoutedTabs = props => {
    const { tabsProps, routeConfig } = props;
    const { url, path } = props.match;
    const tabToRouteMap = {};
    const routeToTabsMap = {};
    _each(routeConfig, (configObj, routeKey) => {
        const routeURL = configObj.getRoute(url);
        tabToRouteMap[routeKey] = routeURL;
        routeToTabsMap[routeURL] = routeKey;
    });
    const defaultActiveKey = routeToTabsMap[props.history.location.pathname];
    const tabPaneNodes = _map(routeConfig, (configObj, routeKey) => (
        <TabPane tab={configObj.label} key={routeKey} />
    ));
    const routeNodes = _map(routeConfig, (configObj, routeKey) => (
        <Route
            path={configObj.getRoute(path)}
            exact
            key={routeKey}
            component={configObj.component}
        />
    ));
    const onTabChange = activeKey => {
        props.history.push(tabToRouteMap[activeKey]);
    };
    return (
        <>
            <Tabs {...tabsProps} onChange={onTabChange} defaultActiveKey={defaultActiveKey}>
                {tabPaneNodes}
            </Tabs>
            <Switch>{routeNodes}</Switch>
        </>
    );
};

RoutedTabs.propTypes = {
    tabsProps: PropTypes.object.isRequired, // As per https://ant.design/components/tabs/#Tabs
    routeConfig: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default RoutedTabs;
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are certain you want to define the tabs explicitly with router then you set a prop in the component:

```
<Route path={"/base/a"} exact={true} render={() => <ComponentBase tab="a" />} />
```

[More info on Route from react router docs.](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#route-render-methods)

I think you would be better off using `props.match.params`that is provided by react router instead of explicitly defining the tabs, [more info and example here](https://jaketrent.com/post/access-route-params-react-router-v4/).

You can than get the value off of {props.match.params.base} and pull that tab.

Comment: So you suggesting we should go with `props.match` which was what we said in the first part of the question?